# Issue with creating weblogic server domain in jdeveloper?

Tags: weblogic, jdeveloper

I am not able to create `weblogic` domain from `jdevloper`!

I am using Jdevloper 12.1.2(12c), when I am try to create domain on default integrated `weblogic server` then that gives me error like this-

wlst > Error occurred during initialization of VM

wlst > Could not reserve enough space for object heap

wlst > Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

wlst > Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I am re-Installed `jdeveloper(12c)`,restart machine,set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable but error still occur.

Please some body help me and fix this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Modify %HOME%\oracle_common\common\bin\commEnv.cmd file setting USER_MEM_ARGS environment variable after ":continue" tag and re-create default domain again from Application Servers view on JDeveloper.

SET USER_MEM_ARGS=-Xms32m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:MaxHeapSize=512m

Comment: I'm not using jdeveloper but this solution works for my case ( invoking wlst from ant ).

Answer (score 0):

This is a RAM problem for your JDeveloper process

Edit the `jdev.conf` file (`~/Oracle/middleware/jdeveloper/jdev/bin`) and add more memory to the file

```
AddVMOption -Xmx1024M 
AddVMOption -XX:MaxPermSize=256M
```

which is 1 GB provided you have RAM available on your machine

Also check if your JDK is the 32 or 64 bit [to match your OS](http://blog.sourcecode24.com/oracle/error-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap-jdev-11g/)

Comment: Thank you for reply JoseK,I try above but Jdevelope cant start,it shows an error 'Unable to create an instance of the java virtual machine at path: ----\jvm.dll

Comment: do u have enough RAM free to assign 1 GB to the process? try with -Xmx512M

Comment: I have also set -Xmx512M ,Jdeveloper run but still same error occurred.

Comment: do you have an ide.conf file in the folder? can you move this to that file?

Comment: Yes,I have added ide.conf file to jdev.conf but still not worked!!

Answer (score 0):

How much RAM does your machine have - you need at least 2GB.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you are using a 64bit JDK